# How can I disable the green frames after a cinematic in UDK?

Tags: udk

These green frames appear in my scene after the display of a cinematic (which I just added recently):

[image]

How can I remove them, ideally without resorting to transitioning the game mode?

Comment: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2013/12/17/f11/3cd/e9228cbda65fb7b184360cf6019115eacef387bf.jpg answer found.

Answer (score 2):

As posted in your comment, the green frames are UnrealKismet references. Uncheck them from the Show menu to hide them.

[image]